# Compare todays dayname and time through array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

Array
(

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Start] => 08:00
        [dayName] => Tuesday
        [dayID] => 2
        [courseName] => Math

    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Start] => 10:00
        [dayName] => Tuesday
        [dayID] => 2
        [courseName] => Geography
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Start] => 14:00
        [dayName] => Tuesday
        [dayID] => 2
        [courseName] => Science
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Start] => 10:00
        [dayName] => Thursday
        [dayID] => 4
        [courseName] => Math
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Start] => 18:00
        [dayName] => Friday
        [dayID] => 5
        [courseName] => History
    )
```

)
What I want to do is , I want to compare the daya nd time now to the values in the array. For example lets assume that it is 7:00 am and it is Tuesday. Then I want to get the Object[0]. But if it is 11:00 o'clock then i need to get the  Object[2] which starts at 14:00 on Tuesday.
It it is Tuesday and 16:00 o'clock then i need Object[3] .

If it is a weekend then i need the beginning of the week which is Tuesday at 08:00 with the Math Course.

I tried to get that using key => value but I mixed up.
How can I compare the Day and then time and in case there is a Course on that combination just pick it up if not just continue checking.

regards
littleblue

Answer (score 1):

```
function getObject($array){
    $timeNow = date('U'); // time now
    $oneHour = $timeNow+3600; // time now + 1 hour

    foreach($array as $num => $one){ // loop in each $array
        $date = strtotime($one->Start); // convert start time to timestamp
        if($date >= $timeNow && $date < $oneHour && date('l', $date) == $one->dayName){ // if all criteria met
            return $array[$num]; // return that object
        }
    }
    return array('no data'); // if no criteria is met return no data.
}


$course = getObject($yourArray);
echo $course->courseName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mix the use of DateTime and a simple min search :

```
$myCourse = null;//initialisation
$myCourseDate =null;
$now = new DateTime;
foreach($array as $course){
   //get the date from the datas
   $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('l h:i',$course->dayName.' '.course->start);
   if($now < $date && ($myCourseDate === null || $myCourseDate > $date)){
      $myCourse = $course;
      $myCourseDate = $date;
   }
}
//at the end of the loop, you've got the expected course
```